# javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error writing PNG file

Tags: java, spring, web-services, tomcat, jpedal

I am using Jpedal tool to convert PDF to Image.
When PDF pages are very large in number and we process it to convert then tomcat gets stopped and **throws Exception-**

```
  javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error writing PNG file.
```

Can anyone please help for this.

```
public boolean createPDF2ImageTask(String sourcePDFAbsPath, String destinationImageAbsPath, Float scalingFactor, String fileFormat, int softLimitInKB) throws Exception
    { 

        System.setProperty("org.jpedal.flattenForm","true");
        logger.info("createPDF2ImageTask ( sourcePDFAbsPath = "+sourcePDFAbsPath+" , destinationImageAbsPath = "+destinationImageAbsPath+ ", scalingFactor = "+scalingFactor+ " , fileFormat = "+fileFormat+ " softLimitInKB ="+softLimitInKB );
        boolean status = true;
        Float newScalingFactor;
        int sizeOfImageInKB;

        //PdfDecoder object provides the conversion 

        PdfDecoderServer decoder = null;
        Map mapValues = null;
        BufferedImage imageToSave = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try
        {

            Helper.deleteFile(destinationImageAbsPath);

            //mappings for non-embedded fonts to use
            FontMappings.setFontReplacements();

            decoder = new PdfDecoderServer(true);
            decoder.openPdfFile(sourcePDFAbsPath);


            mapValues = new HashMap();


            mapValues.put(JPedalSettings.EXTRACT_AT_BEST_QUALITY_MAXSCALING, 2);

            //alternatively secify a page size (aspect ratio preserved so will do best fit)
            //set a page size (JPedal will put best fit to this)
            PdfPageData pageData = decoder.getPdfPageData();
            int width = (int)(scalingFactor*pageData.getCropBoxWidth(1));
            int height = (int)(scalingFactor*pageData.getCropBoxHeight(1));
            logger.info("width = "+ width + "   height= "+height);          
            mapValues.put(JPedalSettings.EXTRACT_AT_PAGE_SIZE, new String[]{String.valueOf(width),String.valueOf(height)});

            //which takes priority (default is false)
            mapValues.put(JPedalSettings.PAGE_SIZE_OVERRIDES_IMAGE, Boolean.TRUE);

            PdfDecoderServer.modifyJPedalParameters(mapValues);                              

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            try
            {
                imageToSave = decoder.getPageAsHiRes(1, null, false);
                decoder.flushObjectValues(true);
                if(imageToSave != null)
                {
                    logger.info("Start saving image as a file");
                    bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationImageAbsPath)));

                    ImageIO.write(imageToSave, fileFormat, bufferedOutputStream);

                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("imageToSave is null, Exception in extractPageAsImage ");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                logger.error("Exception in extractPageAsImage :: "+e);
                logger.error("Exception stack trace in extractPageAsImage :: ",e);
                throw new Exception("Exception in extractPageAsImage :: "+e);
            }
```

> It's throwing Exception - Exception in extractPageAsImage :: javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error writing PNG file!

Comment: Please post your stack trace.

Comment: And it is better to `throw new Exception("Exception in extractPageAsImage", e);` than to `throw new Exception("Exception in extractPageAsImage :: "+e);`.

Comment: @LarsGendner
Hi, these were previous logs.
Now while processing , it stops tomcat unexpectedly and no logs are being printed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to solve this by increasing memory of your Tomcat instance. On Unix platforms this can be achieved by adding some Java options in `setenv.sh`:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms128m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

or on Windows in the file `setenv.bat`:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

Please note that the numbers in the examples above are just examples, as they depend on the memory available on your platform.

Please refer to [Tomcat's RUNNING.txt](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) for further details on how to configure the Tomcat on your platform.